# Slope estimate dependent on covariance?

Tags: regression, bayesian, regression-coefficients, hierarchical-bayesian, deming-regression

I am trying to perform a linear regression with equal errors on x and y (ex =1 and ey=1) in a Bayesian framework (using WinBugs). Using Winbugs (solid line in the Figure), I managed to reproduce the estimate calculated with an Orthogonal Regression (`deming` function in R, dotted line in the Figure)

[image]`

However, if I set ex=ey=100 the regression results in WinBugs change while with the `deming` function do not (as it should be). What am I not understanding? Is this a 'problem' intrinsic of the Bayesian approach?

Here the code used to calculate the Orthogonal Regression with the `deming` function

```
# --------------------------------------------  GENERATE ARTIFICIAL DATA ---------------------------------------- 
A <- 0
B <- 0.5
N <- 1000
X <- rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=2.5) # TRUE x
x <- X + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=1) # OBSERVED x
Y <- A + B* X # TRUE y
y <- Y + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=1) # OBSERVED y

# ---------------------------------------  DEMING REGRESSION WITH EQUAL ERRORS ------------------------------------

orFITeq1 <- deming(y~x, data=data,xstd=rep(1,length(x)), ystd=rep(1,length(y)), dfbeta=T)
b1 <- orFITeq1$coefficient[2]
a1 <- orFITeq1$coefficient[1]

orFITeq100 <- deming(y~x, data=data,xstd=rep(100,length(x)), ystd=rep(100,length(y)), dfbeta=T)
b100 <- orFITeq100$coefficient[2]
a100 <- orFITeq100$coefficient[1]

    # -----------------------------------------------------  RESULTS --------------------------------------------------

> a1
(Intercept) 
  0.0664332 

> b1
           x 
0.0009596685 

> a100
(Intercept) 
  0.0664332 

> b100
           x 
0.0009596685
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you do with frequentionist regression? What with Bayesian? What is your data? What do you change?

Comment: Solving this may come down to seeing exactly how you invoked `deming` and verifying your understanding of its documentation.  In most cases it will not matter what you set the errors (`xstd` and `ystd`) to if they are constant, *because the software will estimate the errors from the data regardless.*  As such, this software is not directly comparable to the Bayes solution.  You might see differences in the `deming` fits when you use heteroscedastic errors, though.  Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: @whuber see edited post. Are you saying that the regression results with the deming function depend only on the data and not on the ration ex/ey that I set? Is this true in general?

Comment: When you set the errors to constant values, Deming regression gives a line passing through the point of averages in the direction of the principal eigenvector of the covariance matrix: in other words, it reduces to PCA (aka [orthogonal regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression#The_case_of_equal_error_variances)).  The actual sizes of the errors in that case do not matter.

Comment: I could imagine that there is a problem with how you define the priors for the variance parameters, but without showing your "Bayesian version of the deming regression" it will be pretty hard to tell you why it doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "linear regression" you mean ordinary least squares regression (OLS), are you forgetting that OLS minimizes error in the dependent variable, so that one would expect different results (e.g. $R^{2}$, MSS, etc.) when swapping $y$ and $x$, while `deming` uses a MLE that minimizes error in both $y$ and $x$? From the first line of `deming`'s documentation:

> Ordinary least squares regression minimizes the sum of distances between the y values and the regression line, Deming regression minimizes the sum of distances in both the x and y direction. As such it is often appropriate when both x and y are measured with error.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight That is precisely what I thought, and why I answered as I did.

Comment: @Alexis I updated the question

Comment: @Alexis I know that with the deming regression I am expecting different results from the OLS and also that if I don't change the ratio ex/ey the results should be the same. The problem is that with my Bayesian version of the deming regression this is not happening.